# Java akka get common things to one place

Tags: java, inheritance, akka

I am using java akka framework. Some of my actors will do same thing in onreceive method. Is there a way to avoid this and get them to a common location. (May be using inheritance)

Problem in detail is like below.

- In some actors it send an ack message based on a condition. This ack
  is send to and external system by another actor.
- This is duplicated in several classes.

Comment: I'd avoid inheritance and look at putting the actor interfaces into a library, then use composition to include the necessary utils / service classes in your actors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because an actor's `Receive` block is a partial function, you can chain `Receive` blocks with `orElse`. This is helpful for sharing behavior among actors and is described in the Scala version of the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/actors.html#extending-actors-using-partialfunction-chaining), but you can do the same thing in Java.

The following is a simple example that uses inheritance, in which the common acking behavior is defined in a base class. However, you don't have to use inheritance and can define `Receive` blocks wherever you want to:

```
import akka.actor.AbstractActor;
import akka.event.Logging;
import akka.event.LoggingAdapter;

public class AckingActor extends AbstractActor {
    private final LoggingAdapter log = Logging.getLogger(getContext().getSystem(), this);

    public static class Msg1 {}
    public static class Ack {}

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
            .match(Msg1.class, m -> getSender().tell(new Ack(), getSelf()))
            .matchAny(m -> log.info("unknown message"))
            .build();
    }
}
```

Actors that share the acking behavior can extend the base class:

```
import akka.actor.AbstractActor;

public class AckingProducer extends AckingActor {
    private AbstractActor.Receive producerBehavior;

    public AckingProducer() {
        producerBehavior =
            receiveBuilder()
                .matchEquals("foo", m -> getSender().tell("bar", getSelf()))
                .matchEquals("ping", m -> getSender().tell("pong", getSelf()))
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return producerBehavior.orElse(super.createReceive());
                            // ^ chain the Receive blocks with orElse
                            // e.g., behavior1.orElse(behavior2).orElse(behavior3)
    }
}
```

You can chain an arbitrary number of `Receive` blocks. Note that if more than one partial function handles the same message, then the first one that matches (that is, the first `Receive` block in the `orElse` chain that matches) will handle the message.